# How can I show that a function is always decreasing?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I am stuck in showing that the function `s[t,j,i]` is always decreasing. If I plot the function, its graph shows that it is decreasing over any interval $(0,2000]$, for example. However, I am unable to get generally `s'[t,j,i] < 0` for any positive integer values of `i` and `j` with `i > j`.

This is my try in Mathematica:

```
γ = 1.26;
ϵ = 0.85;
α = 2*ϵ - 1;
N0 = 400;
r[i_]:=1/N0*γ^i
g[t_,j_,i_]:= \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(h = j\), \(i\)]\((
\*FractionBox[\(Exp[
\*FractionBox[\(\(-α\)*
\*SuperscriptBox[\(γ\), \(h\)]\), \(N0\)]*t]\), \(\((
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∏\), \(l = j\), \(h - 1\)]\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(γ\), \(h\)] - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(γ\), \(l\)])\))\)*\((
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∏\), \(l = h + 1\), \(i\)]\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(γ\), \(h\)] - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(γ\), \(l\)])\))\)\)])\)\)

s[t_,j_,i_]:= -α*r[i]-α*r[0]*(g[t,j,i-1]/g[t,j,i])
Plot[s[t,2,7],{t,1,4000}]
g[t,2,4]
s[t,2,5]//FullSimplify
D[s[t,2,5],t]==0
Solve[%,t]
```

Any views, help is appreciated.

Comment: @mikado; There is a fraction there: `s[t, j, i] // InputForm` results in `-0.0017499999999999998*1.26^i - 
 (0.0017499999999999998*
   Sum[1/(E^(0.0017499999999999998*
        1.26^h*t)*Product[1.26^h - 
        1.26^l, {l, 1 + h, -1 + i}]*
      Product[1.26^h - 1.26^l, 
       {l, j, -1 + h}]), 
    {h, j, -1 + i}])/
  Sum[1/(E^(0.0017499999999999998*
       1.26^h*t)*Product[1.26^h - 
       1.26^l, {l, 1 + h, i}]*
     Product[1.26^h - 1.26^l, 
      {l, j, -1 + h}]), {h, j, i}]`.

Comment: You cannot use `Solve[ ]` for a sum of exponentials

Comment: Try the substitution `/. t->Log[t]`. If it's decreasing in t then it should also be decreasing in `Log[t]` I think.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes is TeX more helpful than Mathematica

$$\sum _{h=j}^i \frac{\exp \left(-\frac{t \left(\alpha  \gamma ^h\right)}{\text{N0}}\right)}{\prod _{l=h+1}^i \left(\gamma ^h-\gamma ^l\right) \left(\prod _{l=j}^{h-1} \left(\gamma ^h-\gamma ^l\right)\right)}$$

You can factor out the exponential. The result is a decreasing exponential for positive constants in the exponent, times a sum of constants. Perhaps, the sum is positive, too.

Comment: Are you serious?  As far as I see the sign of $$ \prod _{l=h+1}^i \left(\gamma ^h-\gamma ^l\right) \left(\prod _{l=j}^{h-1} \left(\gamma ^h-\gamma ^l\right)\right)$$ is unclear because `γ = 1.26;` .

Comment: Also your $\LaTeX$ is not in the accordance of the ``TeXForm` of `s[t, j, i] // InputForm`:$$-\frac{0.00175 \sum _{h=j}^{i-1} \frac{1}{e^{0.00175 1.26^h t} \left(\prod _{l=h+1}^{i-1} \left(1.26^h-1.26^l\right)\right) \prod _{l=j}^{h-1} \left(1.26^h-1.26^l\right)}}{\sum _{h=j}^i \frac{1}{e^{0.00175 1.26^h t} \left(\prod _{l=h+1}^i \left(1.26^h-1.26^l\right)\right) \prod _{l=j}^{h-1} \left(1.26^h-1.26^l\right)}}-0.00175 1.26^i $$

Comment: @user64494 is right. The denominator changes the sign by changing i and j. Also, the Latex code is for Mathematica use.